# how to use y-websocket send a pong message to server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, y-websocket

I am using y-websocket https://github.com/yjs/y-websocket as the server side to sync the online editor message, I am tried to send the pong message like this when receive the server side ping message:

```
const doWsConn = (ydoc: Y.Doc, docId: string): WebsocketProvider => {
    const wsProvider: WebsocketProvider = new WebsocketProvider(readConfig("wssUrl"), docId, ydoc, {
        maxBackoffTime: 1000000,
        params: {
            // https://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html#query-param
            access_token: localStorage.getItem(WheelGlobal.ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME) ?? ""
        }
    });
    const uInfo = localStorage.getItem("userInfo");
    if (!uInfo) {
        console.error("user info is null", uInfo);
        return;
    };
    const user: UserModel = JSON.parse(uInfo);
    const ydocUser = {
        name: user.nickname,
        color: userColor.color,
        colorLight: userColor.light
    };
    const permanentUserData = new Y.PermanentUserData(ydoc);
    permanentUserData.setUserMapping(ydoc, ydoc.clientID, ydocUser.name)
    wsProvider.awareness.setLocalStateField('user', ydocUser);
    wsProvider.on('auth', (event: any) => {
        // https://discuss.yjs.dev/t/how-to-refresh-the-wsprovider-params-when-token-expire/2131
        handleWsAuth(event, wsProvider, ydoc, docId);
    });
    wsProvider.on('connection-error', (event: any) => {
        wsProvider.shouldConnect = false;
        wsProvider.ws?.close()
    });
    wsProvider.on('message', (event: MessageEvent) => {
        console.log(event.data);
    });
    wsProvider.on('ping', (event: MessageEvent) => {
        console.warn("recived ping message");
        wsProvider.ws.pong();
    });
    wsProvider.on('status', (event: any) => {
        if (event.status === 'connected') {
            if (wsProvider.ws) {

            }
        } else if (event.status === 'disconnected' && wsRetryCount < wsMaxRetries) {
            wsRetryCount++;
            setTimeout(() => {
                wsProvider.connect();
            }, 2000);
        } else {
            wsProvider.destroy();
            return;
        }
    });
    return wsProvider;
}
```

I already read the server side and found the y-websocket send ping message like this:

```
const pingInterval = setInterval(() => {
    if (!pongReceived) {
      if (doc.conns.has(conn)) {
        logger.warn('close connection pong, pong:' + pongReceived)
        closeConn(doc, conn)
      }
      clearInterval(pingInterval)
    } else if (doc.conns.has(conn)) {
      pongReceived = false
      try {
        conn.ping()
      } catch (e) {
        logger.error('close connection when ping,' + e)
        closeConn(doc, conn)
        clearInterval(pingInterval)
      }
    }
  }, pingTimeout)
  conn.on('close', () => {
    closeConn(doc, conn)
    clearInterval(pingInterval)
  })
```

but the client side did not recieve the ping message, Am I missing something? what should I do to implement the ping-pong mechenism?

Comment: Doesn't websocket already have a built-in ping pong mechanism?

Comment: it looks like websocket did not have the build-in ping pong mechamism.

Comment: The WebSocket protocol has build in ping/pong messages. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-11.8 They are length limited to 125 bytes. Why not use regular websocket (text/binary) messages?

Comment: my mistake, it seems the standards are not mandantory so different lib have different support. Finally I found the broswer automatically handle the server side ping. did not need to recived and send pong by user coding. still need to coding on the server side to send ping message. it's better for lib to implement all things of heartbeat.